# Autowiring a Long in my @Service class's constructor

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, autowired

Very new to Spring. I want to create a service class that represents a car dealership. Among others, car dealerships have revenue. For that reason, I have a `long` field called `totalRevenue` that I'd like to be instantiating my dealerships with. I have a separate `@Repository`- annotated class for my repository. This is a snippet of what I have so far:

```java
@Slf4j
@Data
@Service
public class DealershipServiceImpl implements DealershipService {

  private long totalRevenue;
  private final CarRepository carRepository;

  public DealershipServiceImpl(@Value("#{ 1000000L }")Long initialRevenue, CarRepository carRepository) {
    this.totalRevenue = initialRevenue;
    this.carRepository = carRepository;
  }
.
.
.
```

I am using the `@Value` annotation based on the information of `[this (rather old) post][1]`. However, IntelliJ seems to not like it. Hovering over the variable reads "Could not autowire..." as you can see:

[image: Hovering over the argument.]

whereas it seems to also not like my use of `@Value`:

[image]

How can I inject a default value in my constructor? I would like for that `Long` field to be provided at the constructor so that I can effectively test the class from a Junit test.

Comment: Where should that value come from? A system property? From application.properties? From a repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @Value annotation to set initial value for `totalRevenue`.

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class DealershipServiceImpl implements DealershipService {

    private Long totalRevenue;

    private final CarRepository carRepository;

    public DealershipService(
            @Value("${initialRevenue:20000}") Long initialRevenue, 
            CarRepository carRepository) {
        this.totalRevenue = initialRevenue;
        this.carRepository = carRepository;
    }

    ...
}
```

And put this property in application.properties (or application.yml):

```
initialRevenue = 100000
```

Also if you will not add this property, the default (20000) would be applied.

P.S. @Value annotation from package `org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation`. Do not confuse with similar Lombok annotation

Hope it will helps you ;)

Comment: Thank you! However, what if I wanted to maintain that constructor with the two arguments? For example, to create and test a new instance of `DealershipServiceImpl`? Would putting the `@Value` annotation in the constructor  argument work, then?

Answer (score 2):

It does not necessary to define the `initialRevenue` in the `application.properties`. Just directly specify the value in `@Value` without `#{}` , it will automatically convert it to the correct data type :

```java
@Service
public class DealershipServiceImpl implements DealershipService {

  private long totalRevenue;
  private final CarRepository carRepository;

  @Autowired
  public DealershipServiceImpl(@Value("1000000")Long initialRevenue, CarRepository carRepository) {
    this.totalRevenue = initialRevenue;
    this.carRepository = carRepository;
  }

}
```

Comment: Turns out I was using lombok.Value instead of org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value, and this _is_ possible with the correct annotation! Thank you.